# connect button to view controller class objective-C  programmatically 

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [connect button to TableViewController in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296573/connect-button-to-tableviewcontroller-in-xcode)

How can I connect my button to another view controller class programmatically thanks in advance , I need the code I 'm really beginner thanks, here is my button code: my vie controller class name is year.m

```
-(void) year:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Year button clicked");
 }
```

**Edit:**

here is code for my programmatically button

```
UIBarButtonItem *yearButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Year" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered    
 target:self action:@selector(year:)];
```

Comment: Ok then my answer is wrong and Amy's answer is correct. Just follow OP's answer

Comment: @Owl where should I put AMy answer?

Comment: @casperOne if it's the same why the answer didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

To add target/action pairs programatically (as opposed to through Interface Builder), look into this method on `UIButton`:

```
addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

Comment: I edit my question can you check it

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. Take a look at this Apple guide about [Navigation Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2). There's a section in there for creating them programmatically. Essentially you have to make sure that the first view controller (that contains your button) is already inside a navigation controller, then in your action method you create the new VC and push it onto the navigation controller's stack.

Comment: Well, nope -- that's true for UIConrols, but UIBarButtonItem is not an UIControl subclass.

Comment: Ah, when the question was posted it didn't originally mention a UIBarButtonItem. It also seems that it's more about how to push a new view controller (hence my linking to that guide) rather than how to set up target/action (what I originally thought it was about).

Answer (score 0):

Create yourButton in `viewDidLoad` method as following way...

```
UIButton *yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[yourButton setTitle:@"YearButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(240, 40, 75, 30);     
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(year:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[self.view addSubview:yourButton];
```

This is your method code....

```
-(void) year:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Year button clicked");
 }
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: thanks for reply but I create my button I have my button I don't know how should I connect my button to one viewcontroller class , I mean after NSLog(@"Year button clicked"); what should I writ that when I press my button it goes to another class

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296573/connect-button-to-tableviewcontroller-in-xcode/10297146#10297146) for your answer

Comment: but it's Item bar button it's not worked that way

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the `addTarget` method (see here: [Bind Action to UI Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545721/bind-action-to-uibutton)).
In your case it would be:

```
[yearButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//the method that gets called
-(IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender {
  NSLog(@"Button clicked %@", sender);
  // do something here
}
```

But if you want to check wether the button was pressed in another view controller you have to look for NSNotifications (see here: [Cocoa Notification Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842737/cocoa-notification-example)). With these you can send messages from one to another class and react to the users input.

Comment: inside (IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender {
  NSLog(@"Button clicked %@", sender);
  // do something here
}  I should write I want to press my button then goes to test.m view that's it

Comment: so you want to make a transition from one view to the other i guess:
`//push it to the navigationController
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailedViewController animated:YES];`
In this case `detailedViewController` is the name of your new view controller you want to switch to in your case it should be `year`.