# Enable text box when checkbox is ON using objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

How do I enable a text box when I check the checkbox through bindings in Cocoa?

Comment: could you please add some more details?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bind the checkbox's `value` and the text field's `enabled` to the same property of the same object—usually either your File's Owner (typically a window controller, view controller, or document) or some kind of object controller (such as an array controller).

Answer (score 1):

First you connect your text box to an IBOutlet.

And instead of using binding, you can set your button to fire an action method when it is touched ([this is called an IBAction and there's a bit more detail in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545721/bind-action-to-uibutton))

When the state of the button (or in your case, checkbox) changes, the IBAction method gets called and based on the state of the checkbox, you can enable or disable your textbox via the outlet you connected.

Comment: An action isn't a delegate method. Delegation involves a protocol, formal or informal, provided by the delegating object; the action's selector is provided by the target (or whoever/whatever is setting the action).

Comment: well duh, yes. I must have been thinking of something else when I furiously typed out my answer at 5 in the morning.